# mysql connection sleep too many, and wait_timeout do not work

Tags: mysql

I have mysql db,i set `wait_timeout` and `interactive_timeout` = 3600 seconds.
my cofnig:

[image]

But when i show processlist, process sleep time greater than 3600s do not killed.
[image]

Update:

[image]

I try restart mysql but still don't work.
I want to kill connections, when it sleep time > 1 hour.

Thank Guys.

Comment: please share **show global variables like 'wait_timeout';**

Comment: @ROHITKHURANA
| wait_timeout  | 3600  |

Comment: are these connections set their session variables during connection. if so, Then that overwrites your settings. Please check at the application end once.

Comment: @ROHITKHURANA i upload picture with config wait_timout

Comment: I'm asking source of connection from id 194, 209, 223 created

Comment: from my worker (for delayed job). i have error `too many connection`, so i want to kill all connection from worker when sleep more than 1 hour, to take slot connection for another worker

Comment: Had you taken restart of your worker after changing wait_timeout?

Comment: I would recommend that restart your worker after changing timeout if it cache during start time. It'll refresh all variables  and then monitor